# In what cases is a tendon injury considered not amenable to surgery?

Tags: surgery, tendons

*Wang, Allan W., et al. "[Autologous tenocyte implantation, a novel treatment for partial-thickness rotator cuff tear and tendinopathy in an elite athlete.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3603857/)" BMJ case reports 2013 (2013): bcr2012007899.* says:

> The tendon injury was considered not amenable to surgery. As symptoms were recalcitrant to physiotherapy and conventional injection, the decision was made for treatment with ATI.

In what cases is a tendon injury considered not amenable to surgery?